# Not using accepted answer option

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Don't get me wrong, it's not about the points (but I do enjoy getting them). It's more of a site cleanup question.

Is there mods that you can ask to mark an answer as accepted, when you clearly resolved issue [See](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569324/garrys-mod-add-on-folder/569326#569326)

If only to get these questions out of the queue, or do they eventually go away anyways?

Comment: I have a canned answer for that one: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)

Comment: RTFM! ;-)  There is sometimes a lack of information on how to use the site, but I vaguely remember reading it somewhere...  ;-)  You have to post this canned comment *just after* you post the answer, because most of the newbies run off and never come back until they have another problem...

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5440/forcing-leavers-to-accept-an-answer

Comment: Maybe leaving a short message in the questioner's inbox like "Your question has got x answers for y days. If one of them solved your problem, please mark it as accepted."  
Or the questioner could see a banner like "Did this answer solve your question? Click on the green tick to accept it, as this will increase the answerer's and your reputation. [accept] [x] [never show again]" below every new answer.

Comment: @Fabby We all know many timnes answers are not accepted while they should, but quite frankly, I think it's embarrissing to ask to accept, even before OP has indicated it works for him or her. You simply should always assume OP is a grown up person, and simply accept the fact that a certain percentage just walks away after the work is done. I'd only ask (mildly) to accept if OP clearly indicates clearly the answer is working.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I've got a few comments saying: "Oops, I didn't know that".  Or even "Oh, I must have pissed off a lot of people by now" so I don't see it as "embarrassing" but as "educating the new users"...

Comment: @JacobVlijm And guess what?  I *just now* told a new user to click the green check-mark on my answer as it doesn't fully answer his question!  So it goes both ways...

Comment: @Fabby I haven't got the slightest doubt on the sincere intentions. What I mean is that OP should *only* be (mildly) suggested to accept *after* he or she indicated it fully works for him or her, and it looks like there is unlikely to arrive a better answer. Naother thing that popped into my mind is that the "bad behaviour" not to accept is definitely not limited to 1- rep users. Looking at the many users with a blank "accept" list. I tend to answer nevertheless if I like the question, being pretty sure the answer will not be accepted.

Comment: Actually, now that I re-read it, That's the one I used to use.  The new one is: **As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, moderators cannot mark answers as accepted, only the person who asked the original question can do that...

*However* once an answer gets a net score of >= 1 the question is considered answered by the system and removed from the count of unanswered questions. So, with cleanup in mind, all the question needs is an answer with an upvote.

Comment: OK. That works. In terms of the next user with problem, I guess if they read whole thing (question, answer, comments) they can figure out what worked and take those steps. Thanks for answering.